# Selecting Organization Appcelerator CLI

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-alloy

How do I select the organization through appcelerator cli ?
I have two organizations, I tried through appcelerator studio option.

File > Switch organization

But it says I have only one organization.

**Edit:**

I have configured `appc` on my windows machinne, and also configured android SDK, now after leaving the system untouched for a week. I'm not able to run any commands related to `appc`, not even able to print appc version, Please help.

Error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?  Is so, can you mark it as answered?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorted out the issues

**Issue 1:** Selecting Organization

Solution:

One of my organizations was inactive hence Appcelerator CLI was considering only the active organization.
We can switch organizations using `Appcelerator Studio > File > Switch organization`

**Issue 2:** Using any `appc` commands gives error `Unexpected token`

Solution:

1. Delete `.appcelerator` folder in `C:\Users\saif\`
2. Reinstall `appc` using `npm install -g appcelerator`
3. Configure appc account using `appc use latest`, followed by `appc setup`

Comment: please comment before down voting !

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to a different organization using the cli this way:

`appc switch --org-id YOURORGID`

You can also log into your organization using the cli tool this way:

`appc login --org-id YOURORGID --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD`

You can find more documentation for the Appcelerator cli options here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference

Comment: How can i know my organization ID ? Is it the organization name itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

- appc logout -D
- appc login 
  Now choose your ORG and go ahead.

Hope this helps.